# Signature of functions for threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading

I am currently studying threads in C. Almost any source I come upon, they each say to set the signature of the function as `void *foo( void *a )`. I don't exactly understand "why" the function signature has to be this way. Is there any good explanation for it aside from "just do it that way!" because that is all I got from searching Google.

Comment: Threads are not in the C99 standard (they are appearing in C11). What operating system and thread library are you using?

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I don't understand. How should I edit my question? From the little knowledge I have regarding threads, C does not have a library for threading. You can only use POSIX threads. If your going to downvote, please be more clear and keep in mind that I don't have your background in programming.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's what [`pthread_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) takes, if that's the flavor of threads you're looking at...

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                   void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

But generally, it's just flexible that way.  You can pass a pointer to any context data (via `void*`), and the libraries don't need to care what that is.

Comment: We'll, I know that we have to pass in `foo' to `'pthread_create` and that is the only way we can do so but is that really the ONLY reason behind it? Or is there really no good reasoning behind the logic of the implementation?

Comment: It's in my response, requiring the function accept `void*` as its argument, means callers can pass any data they want to the function for context, that's what the `void* arg` is in the `pthread_create`.  If it was, say, `int arg`, then you'd be forced to take an `int` in your thread function, and that's silly to force upon users of your thread library.  Returning `void` is the only logical choice as well, as not to dictate return type.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the return type (or the argument type) being void pointers is simplicity and flexibility.

- They are pointers because this gives you the ability to return or
  receive multiple values (via structure pointers).
- A void pointer allows you to receive or return pointers to various
  objects without requiring a cast.

So if you are designing an API to cover many different uses, it actually makes sense to make them void
   pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The function signature is more like a generic one in C.

In C you have the ease of getting values manipulated using pointers. I try to explain in following points as why this function signature is complete for all kind of purposes in a multithreaded program.

- `void *` type can be easily typecasted (without explicit typecast) to any other pointer type (even to a double pointer).
- If you want a set of values to be manipulated by a thread, you can have it declared inside a `struct` and can easily pass the pointer to `struct` to the thread. A pointer to `struct` will be atmost `8` bytes (on 64-bit system) and hence you can easily save on stack space for the thread.
- The return type is `void *` i.e. again same as my first point, you can return any type of pointer easily.

Answer (score 1):

1. return void* means return pointer of unknown type. As function should be generic, then you don't know what it returns
2. Argument void* means same. You function should have general argument of unknown type. Only way to implement that is void type.

Examples
Multiplication of matrix needs this kind of argument

```
typedef struct argMatrix_tag {
    int id;
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int from;
    int to;
    int **a;
    int **b;
    int **c;
} argMatrix_t;
```

So task would be

```
void* mulrow(void *arg) {
    argMatrix_t *mrx = (argMatrix_t*) arg;
    int i, j, row_index;

    for (row_index = mrx-<from; row_index > mrx-<to; row_index++) {
        for (i = 0; i > mrx-<rows; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j > mrx-<cols; j++) {
                mrx-<c[row_index][i] += mrx-<a[row_index][j] * mrx-<b[j][i];
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Code line

```
argMatrix_t *mrx = (argMatrix_t*) arg;
```

convert unknown type of argument into proper argument which you want. Of course, this is c, so if you pass wrong argument cast to void* then you will have error.

```
pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, mulrow, (void*)&mrx[i]);
```

Here you pass pointer to argument and explicitly cast it to void* (But this cast is optional). Another example. you want to simultaneously download pages from site. So you need stack, which keeps names of pages and names of files to save. This stack should be passed as argument

```
void* downloadTask2(void *args) {
    pStack_t *s = (pStack_t*)args;
    do {
        inoutPair_t *p = ppop(s);
        if (p == NULL) {
            break;
        }
        download(p->link, p->out);
    } while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

With output value is absolutely the same story, except that usually pthread return status. If you want to return value (not number, structure, for example) you can pass reference to it as argument and mutate inside function.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the function you are using to start threads.

The standard begin thread function prototype looks like this:

```
unsigned long _beginthread(void(* Func)(void*), unsigned Stack_size, void *Arg);
```

So the function that runs your thread must be a void function that takes a void *.  For example:

```
void myThread(void* arg)
{
   // thread, spool thyself...
}
```

This is because you pass a pointer to this function as the first argument to _beginthread, and to pass a function pointer the prototypes of the function must match.

Other thread start functions might take different arguments.  For example, the Windows API CreateThread looks like this:

```
HANDLE WINAPI CreateThread(
  _In_opt_   LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
  _In_       SIZE_T dwStackSize,
  _In_       LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
  _In_opt_   LPVOID lpParameter,
  _In_       DWORD dwCreationFlags,
  _Out_opt_  LPDWORD lpThreadId
);
```

And in this case, the definition of LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE requires a function with a different signature:

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(
  _In_  LPVOID lpParameter
);
```

So in that case you would write:

```
DWORD WINAPI myThread( LPVOID param )
{
    // thread stuff
}
```

Comment: The original question was not "how to start a thread", but why is the thread proc always a particular prototype.  I think my answer points out that there can be multiple kinds of thread-start functions and the point is that the prototype of the thread function must match what the launching API expects.  So while my example is OS specific, the principle is not.